# tower.js Install error on windows xp x86

Tags: node.js, towerjs

I ran `npm install tower -g`, npm started and here is what I got:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lingo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.logger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pathfinder
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffeekup
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/restler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/useragent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/URIjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/moment
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/geolib
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/validator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accounting
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git CreateProcessW
: ?????????????????

npm ERR! Error: `git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "C
:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.313818
96790117025"` failed with 127
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\lib\utils\exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeExit (child_process.js:360:16)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:465:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at Array.0 (net.js:335:10)
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "tower" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.12
npm ERR! message `git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "
C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381
896790117025"` failed with 127
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

the node version is v0.6.14

I browse into the folder C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\npm-1333984084485, and found the folder is empty. 
If I run shell command `git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381896790117025"` manually, it is ok.

Part of npm-debug.log file:

```
verbose mkdir (expected) error ENOENT, stat 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\npm-1333984084485'
verbose mkdir done: C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\npm-1333984084485 755
silly exec git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381896790117025"
silly spawning [ 'git',
silly spawning   [ 'clone',
silly spawning     'git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git',
silly spawning     'C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381896790117025' ],
silly spawning   null ]
ERR! git clone git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git CreateProcessW: ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ�����ļ���
verbose about to build C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\tower
info unbuild C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\tower
verbose from cache C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\tower\package.json
info preuninstall tower@0.4.0-2
info uninstall tower@0.4.0-2
verbose unbuild tower@0.4.0-2 [ true,
verbose unbuild tower@0.4.0-2   'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\npm\\node_modules',
verbose unbuild tower@0.4.0-2   'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\npm\\node_modules' ]
verbose binRoot [ 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Application Data\\npm',
verbose binRoot   { tower: './bin/tower' } ]
info postuninstall tower@0.4.0-2
ERR! Error: `git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381896790117025"` failed with 127
ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exec.js:49:20)
ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
ERR!     at maybeExit (child_process.js:360:16)
ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:465:7)
ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at Array.0 (net.js:335:10)
ERR!     at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR! 
ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "tower" "-g"
ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
ERR! node -v v0.6.14
ERR! npm -v 1.1.12
ERR! message `git "clone" "git://github.com/viatropos/node.inflection.git" "C:\\DOCUME~1\\ADMINI~1\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\npm-1333984084485\\1333984084485-0.31381896790117025"` failed with 127
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Anyone could help me? thanks very much!

Comment: the bug is fixed by owner of tower, so it can be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Tower.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996645/error-installing-tower-js)