# Error installing Tower.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, towerjs

Strugging to get tower.js installed on my snow leopard macbook. Here is the command and the error:

```
My-Macbook:tower john$ tower new app

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/index.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tower/bin/tower:15:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with Node.js 0.8, what was `path.existsSync()` is now `fs.existsSync()` - the version of tower.js that you're using seems to be incompatible with the installed Node.js version.

Comment: Good call, my node was out of date. Sorted.